# How to read file in C# from POST data from web

Tags: c#, post, parameters, upload

Basically, I'm building a website that allows user to upload file.
From the front end (JavaScript), the user will browse a file, I can get the site to send POST data (the parameter "UploadInput" and it's value, which the value is the file)
In the backend (C#), I want to make a copy of the file and save it in a specific path.
Below is the way I did it.

```
var files = Request.Files;

file[0].SaveAs("\temp\\" + file[0].FileName);
```

The problem I ran into is that I got the error message saying index out of range. I tried Response.Write(files.Count) and it gives me 0 instead of 1.
I'm wondering where I did wrong and how to fix it, or if there's a better way of doing it.
Thanks!

Edit:

I am using HttpFox to debug. From HttpFox, I can see that under POST data, parameter is "UploadInput" and the value is "test.txt"

Edit 2:
So I tried the way Marc provides, and I have a different problem.
I am able to create a new file, however, the content is not copied over. I tried opening the new created file in notepad and all it says is "UploadInput = test.txt"

Comment: How are you posting the data to the server? Did you specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form?

Comment: @Guffa No, and I'm too sure what you mean by that :/

Comment: The form has to have that attribute for the browser to send uploaded files in a format that the server can use. If you don't have it, the file can't be included in the form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they simply posted the file *as the body content*, then there will be zero "files" involved here, so `file[0]` will fail. Instead, you need to look at the input-stream, and simply read from that stream. For example:

```
using(var file = File.Create(somePath)) {
    Request.InputStream.CopyTo(file);
}
```

Comment: what would somePath be? is it the URL of the website? the way the site works is the user browse file and hit upload, by using HttpFox I can see under POST data the parameter is "UploadInupt" and the value is "test.txt"

Comment: @sora0419 `somePath` here was the local path on the web-server; however, I think you need to be a little clearer about what the data is that is being posted. Is this multi-part? or raw body? or...?